# How can I detect if my app is working under Bluestacks/Nox or other emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, bluestacks

Is there a way to detect if my app is working under Bluestacks/Nox or other emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by examining various fields in `android.os.Build` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

eg `Build.BRAND` and `Build.BOARD`