# How to detect whether app is running on NOX/MEMUPLAY emulator?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-emulator, apk

I have gone through below questions,tried each and every method but none of them is working for nox and memuplay emulators as they are able to fake real devices properties.

[Android - how to detect if app running on Nox emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407255/android-how-to-detect-if-app-running-on-nox-emulator)

[How can I detect if my app is working under Bluestacks/Nox or other emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773715/how-can-i-detect-if-my-app-is-working-under-bluestacks-nox-or-other-emulator)

[How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator/35440927#35440927)

Please help

Comment: Related blog post by Commonsware on [Parallel Space/Boxify](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/17/droidception.html). Short answer, [client can always be faked/fooled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8611960/295004) so any anti-piracy efforts must be done in with server side efforts.